# Picking lines with values having higher value

Tags: awk, line, extract, absolute

I am trying to extract certain lines from my input file:

```
2.txt
1   10  11  A   L   X3  -1.1
1   10  11  A   L   X3  -21.1
1   10  11  A   L   X1   1.1
1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  11.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  -11.1
4   11  12  C   T   X1  -11.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  41.1
```

I am trying to extract the lines that are sharing the first 5 columns, but differing in the last two and also the others which does not share the first 5 columns.

And then, I want to keep the line with highest absolute value on the last column.
I have an awk code to get the line with the minimum value, which belongs to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman/), and I have tried to improve his solution to extract the lines with higher absolute value,however it did not work.

My expected output is:

```
1   10  11  A   L   X3  21.1
1   10  11  A   L   X1   1.1
3   11  12  A   T   X2   3.1
3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
4   11  12  A   T   X7   8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X7  41.1
```

My trial awk is:

```
awk ' {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5} !(key in abs) || $NF < abs[sqrt(key^2)] {abs[key] = $NF; line[key] = $0} END {for (key in line) print line[key]}' 2.txt | sort
```

It outputs the lines with minimum negative number, in negative ( not in positive as it should be) , and it does not print the maximum positive number:

```
1   10  11  A   L   X3  -21.1
1   13  21  A   T   X3  -2.1
3   11  12  A   T   X2  -3.1
3   11  12  K   T   X2   7.1
4   11  12  A   T   X7  -8.1
4   11  12  C   T   X1  -11.1
```

Your help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

here is another way

```
awk '{$NF=($NF<0)?-$NF:$NF}1' file |  # take absolute value of last field
sort -k1,5 -k7nr                   |  # sort by the key and numerical value desc                                       
awk '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]++'            # pick the first one (which is largest)
```

Comment: thank you.. but sometimes this code doesnt order the last column descending. what could be the reason?

Comment: `-k7nr` is for the 7th field numerically descending order, however first rows are sorted by the key (first five fields) and the first entry will be picked (it should always be the largest for the same key).  The final outcome won't be sorted by the last field as in your example.  Perhaps I misunderstood an example data will clarify.

Comment: I have found the problem.. It sorts the 0.002 before 0.19 as 0.002 has 4 digits in total and 0.19 has 3...

Comment: `-n` flag is for numerical comparison, what you describe is not expected with `sort`.  Make sure you have the options set correctly.  Otherwise you have a broken sort implementation...